# Switch UNet From LocalHost to IP

Tags: unity, unity-networking

I have set my game up so that I can run one instance as host and one instance as client and I see two people in the room. How do I get from that setup to another computer (as client) connecting to mine (as host) without matchmaking.

I understand I will need a static IP, and have set my router up for port forwarding (I tested it with an FTP server application I made). I am specifically asking for what options you select in the Unity NetworkManager to do this.

Here is my current NetworkManager (I erased the last number in my IP so I dont get DDos):
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors on either the client or the server?

Comment: I take it you have an online scene usually?

Comment: Oh by the way did you know you can get a free AWS instance for a year? You'd need to compile for Linux and upload but generally you can be pretty sure you're not hitting may issues and you get a pretty static ip!

Comment: @MrkFldig no errors, but that's because it is my local host ip. If anyone else tries to connect it doesn't (they click Client in the NetworkMangerHUD and it does nothing). Yes it is supposed to always be online. I will have to look into the AWS